# Don’t touch garments in the morning but you can touch tzitzis?

Tags: tzitzis

I read in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in laws about waking up in the morning that before saying netilat yadayim, one should not touch things such as his eyes, ears, or his garments because his hands are tamei as if. But then it says that upon waking up one should first put on his tzizis, then then do netilat yadayim, and then say the bracha for tzizis. So why doesn’t this “getting clothes impure” concept apply to tzizis? I would think the opposite and you really shouldn’t touch it until you wash because it’s a holy garment

Comment: Where does it say not to touch your garments?

Comment: @shmosel you’re right I just checked and it doesn’t say it, but I 100% remember reading it. I believe I saw it in a commentary/footnote where they say to not touch clothes either

Comment: @שלום What is that?

Comment: It's brought down in [Shulchan Aruch Harav](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3152639/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-1-Laws-Relating-to-Rising-in-Morning.htm#v7), but I don't think he mentions putting on tzitzis.

Comment: Netilat yadayim in the morning is to remove the impurity that gathers on the nails. The nails are a part of the body that is insensitive because it is basically dead. By doing netila, we are preserving our sensitivity, and not be callous to others. Tzitzit are there to remind us about the Mitzvot and therefore also serve this function in a way. Therefore might be less issue contracting this sort of "impurity"? I have heard all of the above in good sources but it is not a halachic answer (you don't have a halacha tag though), and I don't have them to hand, so I've made it a comment for now.

Comment: Back to halacha, you describe tzitzit as a "holy garment" however that's not a rigorous definition. It might be good to qualify your reason that there would be a greater problem making tzitzit impure than any other garment. They are a davar mizva and therefore have a level of sanctity, and must be disposed of in a geniza, for example.

Comment: @RabbiKaii just pointing that that is not universally agreed upon, and according to the Rambam there are no special rules of disposal ומותר להיכנס בציצית לבית הכיסא, ולבית המרחץ.  נפסקו לו חוטי לבן, או תכלת--זורקן באשפה, מפני שהיא מצוה שאין בגופה קדושה.

Comment: @shmosel so then I guess my question is how to reconcile the fact that there it says not to touch your clothes, but in the kitzur it says to put on your tzizit first and foremost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the premise that the prohibition to touch before netilas yadayim extends to garments, the [MB in 4:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.2?lang=bi) states in the name of the Magen Avraham that although there are those who say that, the Gemara seems to say it’s not a problem:

> כתב בסדר היום שלא יגע במלבושיו עד שיטול ובגמרא לא משמע כן [מ"א]

> It's written in Seder Hayom that one should not touch their clothing until after they wash their hands, but in the Talmud, it does not seem that way [Magen Avraham].

However, in the Magen Avraham 8:1 he says that one must first wash and then put on his tzitzis. The [Levushei Serad 8:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Levushei_Serad_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.8.1?lang=bi) questions this ruling, as it contradicts his earlier ruling that says touching clothing isn’t a problem. If so, why can’t you put on tzitzis before washing? He goes on to explain that the M”A meant to say that the Gemara rules that it’s ok, but there’s still room to be stringent like the later authorities. Therefore, he ruled that one should wash first.

> י"ל דדין זה של סדר היום חומרת האחרונים הוא וממילא דלדינא דגמרא היו לובשין הציצית קודם נט"י

He states further, that the Gemara itself is a proof that they put on tzitzis before washing, because in those days this stringency wasn’t followed. He concludes that the Shulchan Aruch argues with this Magen Avraham and follows the Gemara that rules tzitzis should be put on first before washing, as there is no stringency of not touching clothing.

> ונ"ל דמה"ט לא כתב המחבר דברים אלו משום דאזיל לשיטתיה דבסי' מ"ו הביא דברי הגמרא להלכה מבואר דלא ס"ל כסדה"י ממילא יכול ללבוש קודם נט"י

The Kitzur is obviously following the Shulchan Aruch not the Magen Avraham. Your question is based on two opposing views that argue with each other.

(As an aside, RSZ points out that almost everyone touches their kippa before washing).

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch doesn't mention not touching your garments. But it's brought in Shulchan Aruch Harav [1:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3152639/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-1-Laws-Relating-to-Rising-in-Morning.htm#v7):

> the Zohar rules very stringently that one should neither recite blessings, nor study, **nor touch one’s garments, nor walk four cubits**, while the spirit of impurity still rests on one’s hands before they are washed in the morning

And he does rule similarly regarding tzitzis in the morning in [8:20](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269356/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-8-Laws-Relating-to-Tzitzis-and-Enwrapping-Oneself-in-a-Tallis.htm#v20):

> [The following is the procedure] if a person desires to put on his tallis katan immediately upon rising [from bed] **so that he not walk four cubits without tzitzis**. [Since] his hands are not yet clean, he may not recite the blessing. He may [therefore] put it on without reciting the blessing, and after cleaning his hands he should handle his tzitzis and recite the blessing, for handling them is equivalent to putting them on at this time.

But this halacha presupposes you're not following the Zohar, or else walking around before washing would not be an option in the first place, as pointed out in footnote 49:

> This paragraph relates to a person who does not observe the stringency (whose source is the Zohar; see sec. 1:7 above) of not walking a distance of four cubits nor touching one’s clothes before the hands are washed.

So if you're following the Zohar, it seems you should first wash near your bed and then put on tzitzis (assuming you don't wear them at night).